# In a Notes field with a dialoglist, how can I display a blank as "None" for example?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have a field where Yes and No are the valid selections in the dialoglist, the valid values for the field are setup with Synonyms like this  Yes is Y and No is an empty value/blank/nothing.

```
Yes|Y
No|
```

When the document is saved this the field selection of "No" and re-opened how can I get the form field to display the word "No" when the field is blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the two field solution by using a PostOpen formula:

```
FIELD MyDialogList := @If(MyDialogList="";"No";MyDialogList);
@All
```

P.S. I'm not sure what your intention was here, but this is actually not a bad way to deal with the case where you're adding a new field to an old form and you don't want to have to run an agent to add the new field to all previously saved documents. Since formulas just treat missing fields as empty strings, the @If will work as expected.

Comment: One slight clarification: If this is a case where you're doing this to avoid running an agent to update documents after adding a new field to an existing form, then this is'nt actually a bad way of handling it - unless you have (or will have) agents that work against the documents. Even though you should always code agents to call NotesDocument.hasItem() to make sure that fields exist, sometimes you might forget. Running an agent is your best insurance against future problems. I know that sometimes the idea is to avoid large-scale re-replicaiton, but it can be risky in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to accomplish that just with an alias definition.

You could work with two fields to get an empty field for "No":

Your current field let's say "TestUI" of type dialog list would have the choises

```
    Yes|Y
    No|N
```

and an additional computed text field "Test" with the formula

```
@Replace(TestUI; "N"; "")
```

would replace the "N" with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've run into an edge case and you probably will need to assign some value as the alias to "No".

If it is really important to have the value be blank when a user selects No, you could create a second computed field that maintains the alias values. Assuming your dialog list field is called "YesNo", your computed field's formula could be:

```
@If(YesNo = "Yes"; "Y"; "");
```